# Akasha: synchronization was stopped

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, ipc, akasha

I downloaded [AKASHA](http://akasha.world) and started the binary, after the quick setup I always get the message:

> #### Synchronization was stopped
>
> Your machine is currently synchronizing with the Ethereum world computer network. You will be able to log in and enjoy the full AKASHA experience as soon as the sync is complete.

And the following logs:

```
SGE01I0117 15:28:11.384307 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 2048MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/user/.ethereum/geth/chaindata Fatal: Could not open database: resource temporarily unavailable
SGE01geth: exited with code: 1
SGE01geth connection timeout
```

It seems AKASHA tries to launch it's own `geth` node instance from somewhere. I am wondering why? Isn't it possible to just connect AKASHA to my already running `geth` node? Do I always have to stop my own node to run AKASHA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure that it's due to geth/mist wallet and browser running in the background hogging the same port on UDP. But is there a workaround for this?

You can't use Mist and AKASHA at the same time. If one is running the other one can't connect to node.

I am on OS X:

```
error
12:21:08
geth: exited with code: 1

info
12:21:08
geth:spawn:close: 1

info
12:21:08
I0116 12:21:08.244490 p2p/server.go:342] Starting Server

info
12:21:08
I0116 12:21:08.241849 core/blockchain.go:219] Last header: #97869 [1a8f5400…] TD=127629812756 I0116 12:21:08.241868 core/blockchain.go:220] Last block: #97869 [1a8f5400…] TD=127629812756 I0116 12:21:08.241877 core/blockchain.go:221] Fast block: #97869 [1a8f5400…] TD=127629812756

info
12:21:08
I0116 12:21:08.242583 eth/handler.go:117] blockchain not empty, fast sync disabled
```

[image: screenshot]

<del>### Temporarily found the solution:</del>

<del>Open Terminal. Install homebrew by pasting this line and hitting enter. Then Install geth by running each of these in terminal one at a time (copy, paste, hit enter, wait) then Start geth client with some port that you want to use (default is 30303 which causes conflict with geth:</del>

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew tap ethereum/ethereum
brew install ethereum
geth --fast --port "35555" console
```

<del>And now both MIST and AKASHA will run together in harmony.</del>

#### FURTHER UPDATE:

**DO NOT DO THIS AS ABOVE!!** Serves and Marius (developers) said that  Ethereum and Akasha chains are different (currently as it's still in the alpha phase) and there is danger of cross syncing. So far they have not described how to use both apps together!

The Slack discussion screenshot below describes why it is dangerous. So we can't use both mist and AKASHA at the same time currently. Hopefully when AKASHA beta or V.1 is released, that will help.

[image: slack log]